# Edit Material UI drawer content width

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I make the content inside my Material UI persistent drawer have less margin?
[Image of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLxNc.png)

This is the same component code as Material UI's Drawer on codesandbox. [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/deopk)

The margins are right in codesandbox but are to big in my Django and React project.

Here is the code :

```
const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
root: {
    display: 'flex',
},
appBar: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
},
appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
},
menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
},
hide: {
    display: 'none',
},
drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
},
drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
},
drawerHeader: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
},
content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: -drawerWidth,
},
contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: 0,
}, }));


export default function PersistentDrawerLeft() {
const classes = useStyles();
const theme = useTheme();
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
};

const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
};

return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppBar
            position="fixed"
            className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
                [classes.appBarShift]: open,
            })}
        >
            <Toolbar>
                <IconButton
                    color="inherit"
                    aria-label="open drawer"
                    onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
                    edge="start"
                    className={clsx(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
                >
                    <MenuIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
                    Persistent drawer
                </Typography>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Drawer
            className={classes.drawer}
            variant="persistent"
            anchor="left"
            open={open}
            classes={{
                paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
        >
            <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
                <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
                    {theme.direction === 'ltr' ? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : <ChevronRightIcon />}
                </IconButton>
            </div>
            <Divider />
            <List>
                {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
                    <ListItem button key={text}>
                        <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={text} />
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
            <Divider />
            <List>
                {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
                    <ListItem button key={text}>
                        <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={text} />
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
        </Drawer>
        <main
            className={clsx(classes.content, {
                [classes.contentShift]: open,
            })}
        >
            <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
            <Typography paragraph>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum
                facilisis leo vel. Risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Semper risus in hendrerit
                gravida rutrum quisque non tellus. Convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id
                donec ultrices. Odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing. Amet nisl suscipit
                adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis. Cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras.
                Metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo. Mauris commodo quis
                imperdiet massa tincidunt. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. At augue eget
                arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. Lorem
                donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac.
            </Typography>
            <Typography paragraph>
                Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla
                facilisi etiam dignissim diam. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac
                tincidunt. Ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Purus sit amet volutpat
                consequat mauris. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed
                vulputate odio. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in. In
                hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac. Pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et
                tortor. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin
                nibh sit. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend. Commodo viverra maecenas
                accumsan lacus vel facilisis. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.
            </Typography>
        </main>
    </div>
); }
```

I am new to Django and React but since the code is exactly the same as Material UI's Persistent Drawer, i'm guessing the problem is outside the component but i'm not sure how. Is there a way to fix the margins within the component? Or are there any common places that I could look inside my react project that could be messing with my styling?

I tried harcoding the styling but that messed up the margins more on other devices.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you made any changes to the theme spacing?

Comment: @Raythe No, I have not.

Comment: could you perhaps make a basic sandbox with your code?

Comment: I made a sandbox ( Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-cherry-bx62u? ) but somehow the margins are correct in the sandbox and not in vs code. @Raythe

Comment: @Raythe I found the issue. The problem was with a div in my App.js. I removed the div that contained my routes and the margins were gone.